# Cmake external ressource

Tags: c++, cmake

HI I'm beginning to use cmake, And  I like it a lot, I was wondering if there was a command to add an existing folder that contain input file in the build process.

Desired structure

```
project/
   src/
   ressources/someinputData
```

I don't want to copy all the files on resources to the build folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "add in the build process"? Are you files involved in the build process (if yes, how?) or do you want them installed with your targets?

Comment: Non there are non compiled file,Just some input data to test my program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/install.html) to copy your files when using `make install` or building the `INSTALL` project in visual, according to your prefered tool:

```
install(
    FILES /path/to/your/file.s
    DESTINATION /where/you/want/to/copy
)
```

There is also this version to install a whole directory, eventually filtering file extensions:

```
install(
    DIRECTORY /path/to/your/directory/
    DESTINATION /where/you/want/to/copy
    FILES_MATCHING
    PATTERN *.txt  # only copy text files
)
```

Comment: Overkilled solution since I'm just trying to copy (or just link) them in the build folder. But I'll try this solution. Thank you

Comment: Feel free to edit your question with a more concrete example for something less overkilled ;)

Comment: the is method did solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: The file command is probably what you want. file(<COPY|INSTALL> .. See the docs here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html

Comment: Hi, Thank you , I think this is the preferable solution, I use file command with GLOB to generate the sources files, but I didn't expected to be more general. Thank you